# Dúvida com edição de lista mvc, utilizando checkbox e campo editavel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou com uma baita dúvida e mal sei por onde começar, então vou recorrer aos universitários:

Tenho uma pagina `cshtml` (estou usando [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc)). Ela tem uma lista, supondo que os elementos sejam A, B, C, D, E. O valor desses elementos vem do banco de dados e ambos já estão sendo carregados de maneira correta.

Supondo que eu queira deixar disponível para a edição os valores 'B' e 'D', como eu faço? E como eu adiciono os `checkbox` nessa lista?

---

**EDIT**

Estou usando essa propriedade

```
new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } }
```

Porém não funcionou. Ele ainda permite a edição, segue como esta meu código.

```
<td> @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.obs, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } })</td>
```

Comment: Depois que você colocou o `EditorFor`, como ficou o HTML gerado? Pode editar sua pergunta e colocar isso também?

Comment: <input class="text-box single-line" id="item_obs" name="item.obs" type="text" value="teste teste">  este foi o html gerado.

Comment: Acabei por ver que a propriedade editorFor não possui propriedades que a desabilitem, então troquei para textBoxFor, a unica mudança aparente é que todos os meus valores serão convertidos para texto

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar @Html.DisplayFor para os itens que não deseja que sejam alterados?

Comment: @Genisson Sim, você tem razão. Você teria que reescrever o *editor template* pra suportar somente leitura. Vou atualizar minha resposta.

Comment: então @Rsinohara, mas existe um campo onde um certo tipo de usuário pode editar e o outro não, porém o text já ajudo e "resolveu" o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta renderizar sua *View* usando os *Helpers* HTML. Por exemplo:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.A)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.B)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.C)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.D)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.E)
```

Como você só quer deixar B e D para edição, use o HTML para bloquear o acesso ao campo:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.A, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.B)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.C, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.D)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.E, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } })
```

Para `checkbox`, use:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MeuCampoBooleano)
```

Se o campo já for `bool` no *Model*, `@Html.EditorFor()` já gera um `checkbox`.

---

**EDIT**

`@Html.EditorFor()` não suporta somente leitura nativamente (só reimplementando o *Helper*), então o jeito é usar `@Html.TextBoxFor()` para campos de texto.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.B)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.C, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.D)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.E, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Note que há uma leve diferença sintática quanto aos `htmlAttributes`.